# Can't get delete http request to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, postgresql

I am trying to get a delete http request to work. I am using AngularJS in my front end and Node.js and PostgreSQL for the back.

Want I want is to be able to delete a session based on its id and it does but for some reason it only deletes the id of 1 and not the others.

So if I had

id 1
id 2
id 3

My delete request will delete the id 1 but wont work for the others.

Here is my code

HTML

```
ng-click="cancelUserSession()"
```

controller

```
   $scope.cancelUserSession = (userId) => {
    const subtracting = currentIndex - 1;
  if (subtracting <= 0) {
      swal({
        title: "Cancel Session",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: "Cancel",
        cancelButtonText: "Keep",
        animation: "slide-from-top"
      },
      () => {
      loginService.cancelUserSession(userId).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        console.log("session canceled")
        getSessions();
      })
    })
  }
  };
```

service

```
  this.cancelUserSession = (userId) => {
        return $http({
          method: "DELETE",
          url: '/remove-session/' + userId
        }).then((response) => {
            return response;
        })
      };
```

index.js

```
 app.delete('/remove-session/:userId', userCtrl.userCancelSession);
```

userCtrl

```
    userCancelSession: (req, res) => {
    app.get('db').delete_client_session([req.params.userId]).then(response => {
      res.status(200).send(response + "item removed succesfully")
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  },
```

SQL

```
delete from client_sessions
  where client_sessions.id = $1;
```

Comment: can you log what req.params.userId is in your userCtrl?

Comment: Yes it console logs 1 everytime.